# Will I lose requested location updates in a FusedLocationProvider if I set the fastestInterval too low?

Tags: android, google-play-services, fusedlocationproviderapi

I haven't found much documentation on this, and it doesn't really seem very easy or straightforward to test. I'm building a `LocationRequest` for use in a `FusedLocationProvider`. Here is a link to the docs for convenience:

http://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/LocationRequest.html

My `priority` is set to `PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY`. I understand that `fastestInterval` allows my app to receive location updates that were requested by other apps. For our use we want locations that are accurate at the expense of battery life.

If another app requests locations at a lower priority but a faster interval, is there a risk that I'll lose out on my location updates because my `fastestInterval` is already being met with more frequent lower-priority location updates?

Answer (score 0):

If you set the *setFastestInterval(Explicitly set the fastest interval for location updates)* and *setInterval(Which set the desired interval for active location updates)* you make sure that you get update from your update request. other wise you might listen to updates for request made by other apps.